# Debian installer No network

Tags: networking, debian, installation

Hi I'm installing Debian on really standard hardware (LAN: **Realtek RTL8111H** )
so I didn't expect any problem with network connectivity.

During install it fails to configure DHCP so I set up manually. The MAC that ifconfig gives me is mapped-  on the router  -to the IP address I am giving the installer.

pinging gateway IP receives no packets. Many other devices are functional and can ping gateway on the network.

route -n and netstat confirm that its recorded the correct gateway IP.

What do I do now?

Comment: While its 'standard' it seems *really* new - earliest mentions of it seem 2 years ago, and sometimes drivers lag behind.  Maybe  try testing or sid to see what it does?

Comment: Even Debian Testing (currently Stretch) doesn't have the necessary firmware support for RTL8111H. See here: https://packages.debian.org/stretch/firmware-realtek.

Comment: This is upsetting because I can't just throw debian on a new computer. I was hoping that most network interfaces "these days" could run in some sort of compatibility mode (since there is little depth to my understanding of these matters).   What do other people do? I'm sure a lot of people buy a new computer and put debian on it! Any reco on a good compatible network card?

Comment: The installer should ask you for the missing firmware , download the tarball from the link posted by @Larssend , extract the binary to an USB stick . The missing modules will be detect and loaded

Comment: @Chrips, Debian tends to be behind in terms of hardware support due to the project's development cycle. You should try Ubuntu, Fedora, or even Manjaro if you really need to run Linux on your new hardware. If you insist on Debian, get any NIC that uses a controller whose firmware is available in the package I linked to in my earlier comment.